# Is it possible to add a time dropdown with hours and minutes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to add a time dropdown with hours and minutes in the cell. Is this possible? I tried adding two columns with hours and minutes but cannot combine it to get it together.

Comment: for all possible times or just few selected ones?

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to create a list of options like:

[image: 0]

---

and then you just create dropdown from that list:

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BkpLWw6TVUAyvb0JKFn0esSUiIIowAkZSqd9u27cyk/copy)